# Android can't get result from standard camera intent

Tags: android, camera, transformer-model

I'm trying to use the standard camera of the ASUS Transformer EE Tablet. I can open the camera and take a picture. But I'm not able to accept the taken picture. I can cancel or take a new picture. But the accept button doesn't work. Did anyone else had this problem?

On the device installed is Android 3.2.1:

Here's the code:

```
Intent standard = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
standard.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(standard, 100);
```

and

```
if (requestCode == CameraActivity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), data.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    report.getPhotoDefinitions().add(definition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First

> in **if** statement you're checking same requestCode variable

Second

> if you're activity is running in any ActivityGroup context you should implement **onActivityResult** in **ActivityGroup**

Comment: I did override onActivityResult. But I'm never getting there (except I deny the taken picture), because I can't accept the picture in the standard camera